# How to select the date range and update the dates without multiple datepickers?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-datepicker

I'm using react-datepicker and I'm trying to come up with a logic to have 2 fields and update the start and end date using just one date range picker. The logic I wrote here is by having 2 date pickers individually, however I don't want it to be in this way. Also, I'm sticking to react-datepicker because it is allowing me to enter the dates manually.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export default function TableDatePicker() {
 const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
 const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());

 return (
   <div>
     <DatePicker
       selected={startDate}
       selectsStart
       startDate={startDate}
       endDate={endDate}
       onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
     />
     <DatePicker
       selected={endDate}
       selectsEnd
       startDate={startDate}
       endDate={endDate}
       minDate={startDate}
       onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
     />
   </div>
 );
}
```

I also did some research on DateRange from mui/pickers but it is not permitting to enter the dates manually although other expectations are good.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

In `react-datepicker` docs, it have [example](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-for-one-datepicker) about date range for one datepicker

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export default function TableDatePicker() {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);

    const onChange = (dates) => {
        const [start, end] = dates;
        setStartDate(start);
        setEndDate(end);
    };
    
    return (
        <DatePicker
            selected={startDate}
            onChange={onChange}
            startDate={startDate}
            endDate={endDate}
            selectsRange
            inline
        />
    );
}
```

or you can create 2 custom input for contain startDate, endDate and hidden the default react-datepicker input

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

function App() {
  const datePickerRef = useRef(null);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
  const onChange = (dates) => {
    const [start, end] = dates;
    setStartDate(start);
    setEndDate(end);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => datePickerRef.current.setOpen(true)}>
        <input type="text" value={dayjs(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY")} />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={endDate ? dayjs(endDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") : ""}
        />
      </div>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={onChange}
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        selectsRange
        ref={datePickerRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

global css

```
.react-datepicker__input-container {
  display: none;
}
```

You can see in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-example-forked-bfdz09?file=/src/index.tsx:0-1006). Hope it helps!